# What is that attachment on the telephone?

Tags: props, the-wire

In *The Wire*, I noticed there was an attachment on the telephone set. What is it? I encircled it with a polygon.

[image]

Comment: You didn't encircle it: you enpolygonned it!

Comment: Somehow, I knew what this question was going to be about before I clicked it. Kids these days!

Comment: Ah, the days when the phone was a destination.

Comment: Also, so didn't enpolygon the attachment, you enpolygonned the entire set.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Since you mentioned, it is _enhexagoned_. All shapes are polygons.

Comment: @Farhan: All polygons are shapes, but not all shapes are polygons (ex. circles)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That is a [Shoulder rest](https://www.google.com/search?q=telephone+shoulder+spacer&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwipgrqbov3nAhVHD2MBHUTdANcQ_AUoAnoECA0QBA&biw=1130&bih=1058).   This is to help you hold the phone up to your ear by shrugging your shoulder or tilting your head a bit.

It made a lot more sense before cell phones.

Comment: And it would make a lot of sense with cell phones as well - I sometime crank my neck to unholy angles trying to keep the phone on the shoulder, and attending children or other octopuses at the same time. Yes I know, there are Bluetooth speakers, loud speakers and whatever - they are always in the other room, or the phone does not want to follow you when on loudspeaker.

Comment: @WoJ, a permanently attached shoulder rest would make the cell phone rather unwieldy to carry around. A detachable shoulder rest would be in the other room when you need it.

Comment: Still makes sense in office settings, about the only place where corded land-line phones are still commonplace.  Though operators who use the phone all the time are more likely to have a headset of some kind, it does kind of make sense for secretarial type work where the phone is used often but not constantly.

Comment: @EikePierstorff For most people today it would probably be more useful to just use a headset instead of a contraption like that, removable or not.

Comment: @Kakturus There's a rather large cost difference between a piece of foam and a hands free device. I have few calls at work, but when i do have them they last an hour or more. It's not worth it to have a hands free for these few calls, but I definitely want a shoulder rest for them.

Comment: Agree with @Logarr - there's also something to be said for a hunk of plastic that will never get lost, break, run out of battery, or require any change in phone-answering routine whatsoever.

Comment: I took knowing what this was as a first sign that I am getting old.

Comment: @NuclearWang - [One of these](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07GVP9QNN/) plus [one of these](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07FCBHK9Y/)? ;-)

Comment: @Logarr Bluetooth headsets are getting cheaper and cheaper. In cars they're great as well.

Comment: I've yet to see an office IP phone with bluetooth. They all have a line for either a wired headset, or a wireless headset dock though.

Comment: @Logarr Those actually exist, I know of at least one Panasonic series that has that option.

Comment: @EikePierstorff: the attachments I saw at my father's office (France, ~80's) were detachable from the headset. You would attach them when needed. I actually still remember them quite vividly, but yes, you are of course absolutely correct: the detachable version whihc i have in mind would obviously be in the other room like the rest of the handy equipment.

Comment: @WoJ, the tech enthusiasm of my youth has waned in my late forties, and I now first think about how annoying problems really are in relation to the technology that purports to solve them. I now close my blinds by hand and miss the occasional phone call, and in return I am saved from the privacy problems with home automation and the search for the bluetooth gadget charger, and my life is so much better for it. So far everybody important has called again.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I have glorious fun with the "computer has a virus" scammers.  I tell them the phone cord is not long enough to reach the computer.  Which is true.  It ties them up in knots!  They cannot figure out what to do with that scenario.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Clearly, what's needed are [shoulder pads](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=shoulder+pads+women%27s+fashion&t=ffab&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fae01.alicdn.com%2Fkf%2FHTB1ARpSf5OYBuNjSsD4q6zSkFXaZ%2FHongMiao-2018-New-Fashion-Autumn-Women-Top-Shoulder-Pads-Long-Sleeve-Outfits-Casual-Zipper-2-Pcs.jpg), not shoulder rests.

Comment: @WoJ AirPods, bro